# Process list of async tasks immediately upon each task's completion

Tags: python, asynchronous

How can I process the results of a list of `async` tasks immediately as a task is completed?

For instance, the following should display whichever page loads first:

```
urls = ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com']
tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_page(x)) for x in urls]

for page in asyncio.give_me_results_ASAP(tasks):
    print(page.url)
```

Since google loads faster, I'd like it to print:

```
google.com
stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: may be simple way is to add the print inside fetch page?

Comment: Can you explain your priorities a bit more? Is the order the most important thing to you, or the immediacy? If the immediacy is the primary goal, why is it the goal? Would you be open to solutions that get the work done faster even if they sacrifice ordering?

Comment: @BearBrown That's a good point. Though I suppose I had some sort of asynchronous iterator in mind. (That way, I can `tee` out the results in a thread-safe manner but also process them immediately.)

Comment: @user2357112 Immediacy. Ordering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) is designed for exactly this, and returns an iterator of coroutines in the order that the tasks are completed. The first coroutine returned from the iterator will correspond to the first task that completes, and you can `await` on each coroutine to get the result of the task.

```py
# With Python 3.8+
import asyncio
import time

async def fetch_page(url):
    reponse_time = 0.1 if url == 'google.com' else 0.8
    await asyncio.sleep(reponse_time)
    return url

async def main():
    urls = ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com']
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_page(x)) for x in urls]

    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        print(f"{time.time():.3f}", await coro)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

produces:

```
1600821288.178 google.com
1600821288.280 stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Also of interest: [CPython's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L556-L616) of `asyncio.as_completed`.